# How can I set a page as default page of System Configuration Index page

Tags: magento-1.9, system-configuration

How can I set a page as default page of System Configuration Page. So it should open when I click on System>Configuration menu  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the setting on backend page.

– Login to Magento Admin.

– Go to System -> Configuration -> ADVANCED -> Admin -> Startup page

– Select Startup page = Configuration

– Save Config

– Logout

– Login

It would be helpful for your issue!

Comment: I think He is asking for system->configuration not for default page for admin

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change default tab for SYSTEM->Configuartion.

Then modify the `system.xml` file and provide low sort and logout and relogin and check.